# What is the difference between two initializations?

Tags: java

Recently I tried to solve the problem '*Coin Change II*' from the LeetCode [link](https://leetcode.com/problems/coin-change-ii/).

> ***Description**: You are given an integer array `coins` representing coins of different denominations and an integer amount representing a total `amount` of money.
> Return the number of combinations that make up that amount. If that amount of money cannot be made up by any combination of the coins, return `0`.
> You may assume that you have an infinite number of each kind of coin.
> The answer is guaranteed to fit into a signed 32-bit integer.*

Here is the right solution:

> `dp[i]`: the number of combinations to make up amount `i`

```java
public int change(int amount, int[] coins) {
    int max = amount + 1;
    int[] dp = new int[max];

    // the right initialization
    dp[0] = 1;

    for (int c : coins) {
        for (int i = 1; i < max; i++) {
            if (i - c >= 0) dp[i] += dp[i - c];
        }
    }
    return dp[amount];
}
```

Here is my solution:

```java
public int change(int amount, int[] coins) {
    int max = amount + 1;
    int[] dp = new int[max];

    // my initialization
    for (int c : coins) {
        if (c <= amount) dp[c] = 1;
    }

    for (int c : coins) {
        for (int i = 1; i < max; i++) {
            if (i - c >= 0) dp[i] += dp[i - c];
        }
    }
    return dp[amount];
}
```

In the right solution, `dp[0] = 1` makes sure that in the following `for` loop, when `i == c`, `dp[i] += 1`.

So in my solution, I assign `1` to `dp[c]` at first which means that the coin with the value `c` can make up the amount itself when the amount equals `c` so its initial value is not `0` but `1`.

I think the two initializations of the array `dp` can achieve the same thing but results are different. What's wrong with my initialization? What is the difference between two initializations?

Comment: first difference: your solution produces `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if coins contain denomination greater than the amount . for example `change(30, new int[]{1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100})`

Comment: @SharonBenAsher I have fixed my code.

Answer (score 1):

1. 

```java
public int change(int amount, int[] coins) {
    int max = amount + 1;
    int[] dp = new int[max];

    // the right initialization
    dp[0] = 1;

    for (int c : coins) {
        for (int i = 1; i < max; i++) {
            if (i - c >= 0) dp[i] += dp[i - c];
        }
    }
    return dp[amount];
}
```

if we have coins with denominations C<sub>1</sub>,C<sub>2</sub>,...,C<sub>N</sub> we may exchange following amounts:

1. using C<sub>1</sub> only: 0, C<sub>1</sub>, 2C<sub>1</sub>, 3C<sub>1</sub>...
2. using C<sub>1</sub> and C<sub>2</sub>: we adding arbitrary amount of C<sub>2</sub> to C<sub>1</sub> sums:

- 0: C<sub>2</sub>, 2C<sub>2</sub>, 3C<sub>2</sub>...
- C<sub>1</sub>: C<sub>1</sub>+C<sub>2</sub>, C<sub>1</sub>+2C<sub>2</sub>, C<sub>1</sub>+3C<sub>2</sub>...
- 2C<sub>1</sub>: 2C<sub>1</sub>+C<sub>2</sub>, 2C<sub>1</sub>+2C<sub>2</sub>, 2C<sub>1</sub>+3C<sub>2</sub>...
- ...
- KC<sub>1</sub>: KC<sub>1</sub>+C<sub>2</sub>, KC<sub>1</sub>+2C<sub>2</sub>, KC<sub>1</sub>+3C<sub>2</sub>...

3. etc.

on each step we are getting unique combinations because that is how we build amounts: since on previous step all combinations was unique adding new coin does not break uniqueness, and the only thing remains is to count duplicate amounts.

2.

```
public int change(int amount, int[] coins) {
    int max = amount + 1;
    int[] dp = new int[max];

    // my initialization
    for (int c : coins) {
        if (c <= amount) dp[c] = 1;
    }

    for (int c : coins) {
        for (int i = 1; i < max; i++) {
            if (i - c >= 0) dp[i] += dp[i - c];
        }
    }
    return dp[amount];
}
```

in your case you are obviously breaks the idea of unique combinations, because introducing the coin with new denomination does not guarantee us uniqueness anymore: that coin has been used previously.

Consider following: let we have coins 1 and 2 and would like to exchange 3:

- #0, dp[]: [0, 1, 1, 0]
- #1, dp[]: [0, 1, 1 + dp[1] = 2, 0 + dp[2] = 2] = [0, 1, 2, 2]
- #2, dp[]: [0, 1, 2, 2 + dp[1] = 3] = [0, 1, 2, 3] - here we got duplicate, cause we have counted {2,1} from #1 and {1,2} from #2 as different combinations

Comment: Could you explain one more time why the right initialization can achieve the effect you mentioned in your point 1? I still have problem understanding the process of getting unique combinations by using `dp[0] = 1`.